# How can I find the version of all Terraform providers in a workspace?

Tags: terraform

I can't find the canonical way to report the version of a specific terraform Provider, in this case the AWS provider. I can find a binary that seems be named with version information:

```
$ ls .terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/
lock.json
terraform-provider-aws_v1.0.0_x4
```

But no other reference to `v1.0.0_x4`, or any other version.

I'm imagining some command like `terraform providers --version`, which currently will just print out the Terraform version.

Speaking of which, I'm using Terraform v0.10.7.

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with v0.12.x, the `version` command is the simplest way to get provider versions:

```shell
terraform version

#=>

Terraform v0.13.5
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread v1.4.0
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.51.0
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm v2.0.2
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v2.0.1
 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.0.0
```

For further info, check the Terraform CLI reference [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/providers.html).

Detailed provider info can be obtained in JSON format with:

```shell
terraform providers schema -json

#=>

{"format_version":"0.2","provider_schemas":{"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp . . .
```

Answer (score 18):

Provider versions are included in the output of the `version` command:

```
terraform version

#=>

Terraform v0.12.x
on . . .
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/. . .
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/. . .
. . .
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the only way I'm aware of.  I presume that if that isn't how it's supposed to be done, when you report a bug the terraform developers will tell you how to do it differently.